# How to use $.Ajax in Post request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to insert a new record in my MongoDB through a local restful API. Using postmen I am able to do so however if I use the webpage i created I get null results. Does anybody see what i do wrong?

Here is the code I used on the clienside.I uze serializeObject library (see github : https://github.com/hongymagic/jQuery.serializeObject)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="submissionForm" name="submissionForm">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Recommendation" class="control-label"></label>
                <textarea asp-for="Recommendation" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Recommendation" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $("#submissionForm").submit(function (event) {
            var jsonObject = $("#submissionForm").serializeObject();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: '/api/recommendations/',
                data: jsonObject,
                success: function (response) {
                    swal('succes', '', 'success');
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
</script>
```

In postmen I am able to post some Json DATA as a POST request

=> This works fine.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML form, it is hard to say. Please add your HTML for the form to your post.

Comment: Is page you are requesting from on that same port `51403`? If not it is a different origin and requires CORS implementation on that endpoint or using a proxy. Postman is not subject to CORS restrictions

Comment: Oh...also `'POST'` should be `'GET'`  if you are using query params in url. Also `GET` is default if you remove `type` completely

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the url that works in Postman that you want to make a GET request not POST

Change `type:'Post'` to `type:'GET'` or remove `type` completely since default is `'GET'`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in multiple steps.

1.) using the Serializeobject library (available on githib) I serialized the formData in a correct form.

2.) then used JSON.stringify to create a correct body for the post request.

Solution:

```
$("#submissionForm").submit(function (event) {
    var jsonObject = $("#submissionForm").serializeObject();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType:'json',
        url: '/api/recommendations/',
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
    });
    $("#submissionForm") = "";
    return false;
});
```